# Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve src/app/app.component.css?ngResource Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, compiler-errors, node-modules

I'm facing this 3 problems that I still can't understand where your mistakes are.

Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:/Users/DexSh/desktop/C# Angular/Testing/src/app/app.component.css?ngResource' in 'C:\Users\DexSh\desktop\C# Angular\Testing'

Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:\Users\DexSh\desktop\C# Angular\Testing\node_modules\webpack-dev-server\client\index.js?protocol=auto%3A&username=&password=&hostname=0.0.0.0&port=0&pathname=%2Fng-cli-ws&logging=info&overlay=%7B%22errors%22%3Atrue%2C%22warnings%22%3Afalse%7D&reconnect=10&hot=false&live-reload=true' in 'C:\Users\DexSh\desktop\C# Angular\Testing'

Error: The loader "C:/Users/DexSh/desktop/C# Angular/Testing/src/app/app.component.css" didn't return a string.

when using ng build returns this

```
Warning: ▲ [WARNING] Comments in CSS use "/* ... */" instead of "//" [js-comment-in-css]

    C:/Users/DexSh/desktop/C# Angular/Testing/src/app/app.component.css:1:18:
      1 │ /******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
        ╵                   ~~



Warning: ▲ [WARNING] Unexpected "(" [css-syntax-error]

    C:/Users/DexSh/desktop/C# Angular/Testing/src/app/app.component.css:1:9:
      1 │ /******/ (() => { // webpackBootstrap
        ╵          ^





Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:/Users/DexSh/desktop/C# Angular/Testing/src/app/app.component.css?ngResource' in 'C:\Users\DexSh\desktop\C# Angular\Testing'

Error: The loader "C:/Users/DexSh/desktop/C# Angular/Testing/src/app/app.component.css" didn't return a string.
```

Can anyone tell me what's causing this, it's in every project

Waiting for a normal build and project execution

Comment: First of all, using a `#` in your folder path isn't a very good idea... You might want to change your `C# Angular` folder name to something without spaces or special symbols. Once you've changed that, you're going to want to fix the syntax errors in your css file(s) (ex. `app.component.css`) to allow the compiler to load the contents correctly.

Comment: I thank you too much, I was curious trying to identify the problem and forgot the possibility of being the name of the root folder, I use folders in this style but in other projects and never had problems, but I will use without special characters.
the syntax is not in trouble I just checked and it's perfect, apparently it was just the name of the folder, thanks there for the alert

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you have a # in your folder name -> (C# Angular).
This f. problem made me to go on rampage too...

Answer (score 0):

Please remove '#' from your folder or subfolder.